# Read text files from the list of paths python

Tags: python, text

I have list of text files and I want to read them and write them to the directory.

```
list_text=["c:\\users\\sva\\abc.txt", "c:\\users\\sva\\mno.txt"]

    for file in list_text:
        with open(file,'r') as data:
            txt_file = data.readlines()

    with open(txt_path,'w') as out:
        out.write(txt_file)
```

getting error: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`

Comment: Use `read()` not `readlines()`. read returns the whole file as a `str`readlines returns each line of the file as a `str` within a `list`

Comment: `readlines()` returns a `list` of strings, not a single string.

Answer (score 2):

The `readlines` method returns a list of lines from a file. The `write` method requires a string argument, but you're passing a list argument. You can write each of the individual lines instead:

```
for line in txt_file:
    out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use read() and not readlines(), does this solve your problem?